# Errors with MKMapkit won't let me display markers onto map

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mapkit

I'm having issue with my JSON response. For some reason every time that I run the program I end up with a threading error, and perhaps it had to do with the error..? I'm trying to take a JSON response and populate a map with a set of markers based on the JSON request.

```
NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
     queue:queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
         if([data length] > 0 &&
            error == nil){
             NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

             if (jsonData != nil){
                 NSError *error = nil;

                 self.results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


                 if(error == nil)

                     self.locations = _results;
                 for (NSDictionary *locations1 in self.locations){
                     CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate =
                     CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([locations1[@"latitude"] doubleValue], [locations1[@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
                     Annotation *annotation2 = [[Annotation alloc] init];
                     annotation2.coordinate = annotationCoordinate;
                     annotation2.title = locations1[@"name"];
                     annotation2.subtitle = nil;
                     [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation2];
    **ERROR: sending 'Annotation *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<MKAnnotation>'
                 }
```

I'm not sure what would be wrong with my delegate? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you created a class which contains details of the annotaions like -title,CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate etc.. which should be a subclass of <MKAnnotation> ?? and then import that class in the class where you are trying to create annotations?/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is undoubtedly that `Annotation` is not defined to conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol. It should be defined as something like:

```
@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
// ...
@end
```

Or you can replace `Annotation` with `MKPointAnnotation` and the code should also work. (Do you really need your own annotation class?)

Finally, and unrelated, you are performing `dataWithContentsOfURL` within the completion block, but that's unnecessary because the `sendAsynchronousRequest` already retrieves the data for you and it's passed to your `completionHandler`.

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
     if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
         NSError *error = nil;

         self.results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

         if (error == nil)
             self.locations = _results;

         for (NSDictionary *location in self.locations) {
             CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([location[@"latitude"] doubleValue], [location[@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
             Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
             annotation.coordinate = annotationCoordinate;
             annotation.title = location[@"name"];
             annotation.subtitle = nil;
             [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
         }
     }
 }];
```